# Hide reorder button in a multifield

Tags: extjs, aem

I have a dialog with a multifield with custom xtype. As per the requirement, I don't require the re-ordering functionality of the multifield elements. Is there a way to hide these buttons.

Dialog xml is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="{Long}800"
    width="{Long}1200"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <tabs
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Questions &amp; Answers">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <tabs
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        addItemLabel="Add a question"
                        fieldDescription="Note: &#xa;1. Add the questions first in a row.&#xa;2. Please select answer type before start adding the answers."
                        name="./questionStack"
                        xtype="multifield">
                        <fieldConfig
                            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                            xtype="apps.nirmal.widgets.configurableQandAfield"/>
                    </tabs>
                </items>
            </tabs>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

[image: the up arrow and down arrow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the API documentation at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html

There you see a boolean property in the Multifield configuration properties to disable ordering:

> orderable : Boolean
>
> If the list of fields should be orderable and Up/Down buttons are
>   rendered (defaults to true).